# control the order in which property transitions occur?

Tags: css

If a create some simple rules with a transition:

```
.foo {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
.foo.is-hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -9999;
    left: -9999;
}
```

i am dynamically adding and removing the `is-hidden` class with js.

`<div class="foo">`  ---->  `<div class="foo is-hidden">`

when i do this, I would like the opacity transition to happen *before* the absolute position flips it off the screen.

can this be done with just transition? or do i somehow leverage a keyframe animation?  I have not done such a thing before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) in conjunction with transition:

```
.foo {
  transition: opacity 1s ease, top 1s, left 1s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 1s, 1s;
}
```

In my Fiddle, I set opacity to 0.5 so you can see the effect:

**http://jsfiddle.net/5knxvkc0/**